# AMP <a> tags are being hidden by :root CSS

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I'm working on the AMP website [http://trentontelge.com/](http://trentontelge.com/index.html). I have SVG social media links in `<a>` tags at the bottom of the page. Google's AMP validator says the page is valid code, and everything else displays properly, but for some reason, AMP is generating some CSS and appending to my `<head>` that display:none's the anchors for my social links. How do I stop this from being appended?

Here is the code for one of the links:

```
<a class="social-link" itemprop="sameAs" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href="https://github.com/trenton-telge">
    <amp-img layout="responsive" width="1" height="1" alt="GitHub" class="social-button-img" src="./img/social/github.svg" >
        <div fallback>GitHub</div>
    </amp-img>
</a>
```

and CSS:

```
.social-button-img{
        margin: .05in;
        max-height: 15vw;
        max-width: 15vw;
        height: .7in;
        width: .7in;
    }


    /* unvisited link */
    .social-link:link {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
        transition: opacity .5s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    /* visited link */
    .social-link:visited {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
        transition: opacity .5s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    /* mouse over link */
    .social-link:hover {
        opacity: .5;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
        transition: opacity .5s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    /* selected link */
    .social-link:active {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
        transition: opacity .5s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
```

And here is the script that is being appended to the bottom of my `<head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
    :root [href^="https://www.amazon."][href*="tag="],
    :root .social-link,
    :root img[alt="Facebook"],
    :root img[alt="Google+"],
    :root img[alt="LinkedIn"]
        { display: none !important; }
    :root *[xsscq7p][hidden] { display: none !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: Is the svg valid?

Comment: @Chris W. All five SVGs are valid

Comment: Note that the `:root` isn't the cause of the problem, the `!important` is. Otherwise the solution would have been to simply add some more elements to your selector, i.e. change `.social-link` to  `:root body .social-link`. Now it's not so straightforward.

Comment: Maybe add some JavaScript onload that removes the superfluous style block.

Comment: @Mr Lister The weird thing is that both Javascript and !important are banned in AMP, yet this page is still valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page appears to be valid AMP and I'm unable to reproduce what you're describing on my PC.

Perhaps most importantly, the `<style>` tag that you're referring to most likely isn't added by AMP. The only CSS added by AMP is in [amp.css](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/css/amp.css) and [searching the AMPHTML repo for "social-link"](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/search?q=social-link&type=Code) yields no results. My best guess is that it's added by a browser extension (perhaps some ad / tracking blocker) or something similar. Can you try to reproduce in a different browser or on a different device?

Comment: That is indeed what it was - AdNauseum being overly aggressive. Thanks, I was going crazy.